# Why does Rust use two bytes to represent this enum when only one is necessary?

Tags: enums, rust, memory-layout

It appears to be smart enough to only use one byte for A, but not smart enough to use one byte for B, even though there are only 8*8=64 possibilities. Is there any way to coax Rust to figure this out or do I have to manually implement a more compact layout?

[Playground link.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3961046e2f7574fff93c03a2b3b60c38)

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

enum A {
    L,
    UL,
    U,
    UR,
    R,
    DR,
    D,
    DL,
}

enum B {
    C(A, A),
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", std::mem::size_of::<A>()); // prints 1
    println!("{:?}", std::mem::size_of::<B>()); // prints 2
}
```

Comment: That's because rust's enums are the size of its largest variant. In this case, `A` is the size of a `u8`, and therefore there is _two_ bytes required to fit _two_ `A`s in `B`, as there is no compile-time micro optimizations like this. Anyway, what if the packed version of this was slower to use than the unpacked version?

Comment: one word, implemented behavior.

Comment: @OptimisticPeach: it's certainly possible that it would be worse on some platforms/use-cases, but with memory latencies nowadays usually smaller data structures make up any unpacking time through having fewer cache misses. I am going to have fairly large vectors of these objects I'm going to be accessing semi-randomly, so cache misses are a concern for my use case. I'd be fine with something I have to opt into but that still saves me the work of manually doing the packing logic myself.

Comment: Rust can do enum layout optimizations in some more limited cases, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/45225 for example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both bytes are necessary to preserve the ability to borrow struct members.

A type in Rust is not an ideal set of values: it has a data layout, which describe how the values are stored. One of the "rules" governing the language is that putting a type inside a `struct` or `enum` doesn't change its data layout: it has the same layout inside another type as it does standalone, which allows you to take references to struct members and use them interchangeably with any other reference.*

There's no way to fit two `A`s into one byte while satisfying this constraint, because the size of `A` is one whole byte -- you can't address a part of a byte, even with `repr(packed)`. The unused bits just remain unused (unless they can be repurposed to store the enum tag by niche-filling).

**Well, `repr(packed)` can actually make this untrue. [Taking a reference to a packed field can cause undefined behavior](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27060), even in safe code!*

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to have some sort of macro that would make a compact representation of B, that would involve generating multiple possible representations of A and implementing conversions for you to get the best of both worlds...