# Is it possible to model LLVM-like inheritance hierarchy in Rust using enums?

Tags: enums, rust

By saying LLVM-like inheritance hierarchy, I mean the way to obtain runtime polymorphism described in this documentation: https://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html.

It is easy to implement the same **feature** in Rust using enums, like:

```rust
enum Shape {
  Square(Square),
  Circle(Circle)
}

enum Square {
  SquareA(SquareAData),
  SquareB(SquareBData),
}

enum Circle {
  CircleA(CircleAData),
  CircleB(CircleBData),
}
// assume ***Data can be arbitrarily complex
```

However, the **memory layout** is inevitably different from LLVM-like inheritance hierarchy, which uses a single integer field to record the discriminant of the type. Though current rustc already has a lot of optimizations on the size of enums, there will still be two integer field to record the discriminant in a `Shape` object in the above example.

I have tried some ways without success, in which the closet to LLVM-like inheritance hierarchy in my mind is to enable nightly feature `arbitrary_enum_discriminant` and assign each variant of the enum an discriminant:

```rust
#![feature(arbitrary_enum_discriminant)]
enum Shape {
  Square(Square),
  Circle(Circle)
}

#[repr(usize)]
enum Square {
  SquareA(SquareAData) = 0,
  SquareB(SquareBData) = 1,
}

#[repr(usize)]
enum Circle {
  CircleA(CircleAData) = 2,
  CircleB(CircleBData) = 3,
}
```

It is perfectly possible for `Shape` to go without its own discriminant, since its two variants have non-intersecting discriminant sets. However, rustc still assigns a integer discriminant to it, making it larger than `Square` or `Circle`. (rustc version: `rustc 1.44.0-nightly (f509b26a7 2020-03-18)`)

So my question is: is it on earth possible in Rust to use enums to model LLVM-like inheritance hierarchy, with only a single integer discriminant in the top level "class"?

Comment: I think this is answered by [Why does Rust use two bytes to represent this enum when only one is necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499156/why-does-rust-use-two-bytes-to-represent-this-enum-when-only-one-is-necessary)

Comment: The quick version: You can't merge the discriminants because doing so would make it impossible to borrow the `Square` from a `Shape::Square` variant (it would have a different layout when inside `Shape` than outside).

Comment: @trentcl Not the same thing: in the OP's case, he has ensured that the child discriminants are non-intersecting, so the child layout wouldn't change between inside and outside.

Comment: My bad. In that case I think it is instead a duplicate of [Why is this Rust enum not smaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57326734/3650362) The niche-filling optimization isn't yet smart enough; it only knows how to handle enums with exactly one nonempty variant. I tried to improve this and I wasn't clever enough; if you think you can do better, the linked issue is a good place to start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this Rust enum not smaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326734/why-is-this-rust-enum-not-smaller)

Comment: Agree. See in particular [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46213#issuecomment-415807521) in the linked issue.